# 'net usershare' returned error 255: [2023/03/19 14:37:29, 0] ../../lib/util/debug.c:1100(reopen_one_log)

Tags: command-line

```
'net usershare' returned error 255: [2023/03/19 14:37:29,  0] ../../lib/util/debug.c:1100(reopen_one_log)
  reopen_one_log: Unable to open new log file 'scan/log.net': No such file or directory
net usershare add: share name /home/monof_senior_operation/desktop/scan contains invalid characters (any of %<>*?|/\+=;:",)
```

Comment: Is this a bug report? Because this site isn't for bug reports..

Comment: not bug reports

Comment: But it isn't a question either.. 

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.